# sectioned UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am making an application for the iPhone, in which I am creating UITableView with 2 sections. I have created sections parts of UITableView, but the problem is that I need different images in every cell of each section. Does anyone has any solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's very easy. Have you this in your datasource yet:?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Add the following code to it:

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%i",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0){
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"justanimage.png"]];
    }else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1){
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"justanimage1.png"]];
    }else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0){
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"justanimage2.png"]];
    }else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1){
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"justanimage3.png"]];
    }
}
```

You can also save your data in a NSMutableArray, but that's a little bit more complicated.

Comment: hi tim
i have tried ur code but it's giving me the 4 error in every line of [cell.imageView setimage:.....] "imageView is not a structure or union"

Comment: Well, in that case, I guess you have an older version of the iPhone SDK. Do you have 3.0 or higher? Else you have to do it as following: [cell setImage:... and change cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; in cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

Comment: thanx i am earlier using 2.2.1. dts why its giving me error. it works perfectly in  3.0

Comment: nw, i want to show selected images to next view. how'll i do it

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView image]];
[vc setView:iv];
[yourNavController pushViewController:vc animated:TRUE];
}

Comment: hi time it's working, but image is taking full view space i need it take only space which i hav take uiimageview in next view nib file i hav txt 2 which i hav already showed it in next view. but your code hiding the txt value. so hw'll get rid of ds. thanx 4 d reply